# How to configure declarative service in CQ5

Tags: adobe, osgi, aem, apache-felix

How to configure declarative service through OSGI console in CQ5.
I was able build sample service, bundled code i got jar and installed through bundle from 
OSGI console

Comment: You may find [these instructions](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_osgi.html#Using%20the%20Apache%20Felix%20Web%20Management%20Console) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The first step is define your service has having configuration parameters.  You might have something like this:

```
package com.sample.osgi;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Modified;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;

@Component(label = "Service Label", description = "Service Description", metatype = true, immediate = true)
public class ConfigurableService {

    @Property(value="default value", label = "Sample Parameter", description = "Example of a component parameter")  
    private static final String SAMPLE_PARAM_NAME = "param.one"; 

    @Activate
    protected void activate(final Map<String, Object> props) {
        this.update(props);
    }

    @Modified
    protected void update(final Map<String, Object> props) {        
        System.out.println(props.get(SAMPLE_PARAM_NAME));
    }

}
```

Once you have your service, you should use maven to generate the scr descriptors, create your bundle and deploy it to your local server.  This is described on [this page](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/developing/developmenttools/developing-with-maven.html#Creating%20the%20project%20structure).

Once you've deployed you should be able to see your service in the felix console on your server.  For example:

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.sample.osgi.ConfigurableService
```

As we added an update method with the @Modified annotation, your component will receive updates to the configured values as they are made with calls to that method.

You can find more information on the SCR annotations [on the felix site](http://felix.apache.org/site/scr-annotations.html#SCRAnnotations-Service)